# java JTree deselecting a node that is already selected

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am developing a java application that uses a JTree. What i would like to archive is that when i click on a node that is already selected it gets deselected.

My current solution is to add a mouse listener and a tree selection listener to the jtree. But the problem is that valueChanged gets called only if there is a change in selection (and not if you select the same node twice). To fix this i added a boolean which indicated if the node was clicked for the first time and then i handle the deselect in the mouseReleased function. This works but the problem now is if the node has children and you want to expand it the node gets deselected and reselected again (which i dont want).

How could i fix this problem? Is there any better way of deselecting a already selected node?

The code:

```
public void initComponents()
{
    elementsTree.addTreeSelectionListener(this);
    elementsTree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
           TreePath tp = elementsTree.getPathForLocation(me.getX(), me.getY());
           if (tp != null)
           {
             if(!nodeSelected && elementsTree.getSelectionModel().isPathSelected(tp) )
                   {
                        elementsTree.getSelectionModel().removeSelectionPath(tp);
                   }
                }
                nodeSelected = false;
             }
        });
 }

 public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e)
 {
    nodeSelected = true;
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: implement a custom TreeSelectionModel that toggles the selection in set/add/removeTreeSelectionPath (or whatever the exact method names are) I faintly remember that there's an example extending DefaultListSelectionModel somewhere on the old sun swingconnection site, not sure if it's still up - just apply that to the DefaultTreeSelectionModel.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the method `clearSelection()` from `JTree`.